# How can the football manager Bygfoot be installed on Debian 12?

Tags: debian, package-management

When I try to install Bygfoot in Debian 12, I get the following error:

Running

```shell
sudo apt-get install bygfoot
```

in order to install Bygfoot in Debian 12.
I get the following error:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Can somebody help me on this? I need a step by step solution.

Comment: Ia that the full output you're getting?

Comment: so, what happens when you manually run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to correct the problem?

Comment: The following outpu:

Package bygfoot is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'bygfoot' has no installation candidate

Comment: How do set the background color of your typing in here?

Comment: In a website it says that I should:
"edit your sources.list file appropriately and execute apt-get install bygfoot."
But I don´t know how to edit that file and what to write in the new sources.list.

Answer (score 0):

Bygfoot is not available anymore in the software repository of the Debian 12 release, Debian 11 was the last release it was included. (see [packages.debian.org](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=bygfoot))

You can download Bygfoot as a .deb software package file from the [SourceForge page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bygfoot/files/bygfoot-unstable/bygfoot-2.3.2/). Choose bygfoot_2.3-2_amd64.deb (or bygfoot_2.3-2_i386.deb if you have a 32 bit CPU).

Another option would be to either download the package from [this page](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/bygfoot)
or add the bullseye repository to your system.